# WSO2 CEP - Out of Memory

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

We are seeing out of memory errors on CEP. The thread dump shows that there were around 32000 threads sleeping on monitor. Also even though CEP JVM options specifies to generate the HeapDump on outofmemory, we dont see any heap dump generated..
Please advice. (CEP JVM -Xms256m -Xmx1536m )

1) The Cassandra is disabled on this CEP
2) CEP version is 2.1.0
3) The CEP is fronted by WSO2 ESB (using BAM Mediator).
4) Apart from sending the actual payload data to CEP, the ESB is also sending a periodic heartbeat to CEP (every 15 ec).
5) We also have configured JMX Agent on ESB which is monitoring the CEP every 15 mins (cpu/memorythreads)
6) No heap dump found even though -XX:HeapDumpPath= parameter is specified

- The CEP ran continously for 7 days before this OOM. After restart we observe that the thread count is steadily increasing at rate of approx 4000-5000 threads per day

CEP logs..

```
[2013-06-10 05:31:49,040] ERROR -  Thread Thread[ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor  WriteCheckTimer,5,main] died {org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:727)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:657)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.writeCheck(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:153)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor$2.run(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:117)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
[2013-06-10 05:31:49,040] ERROR -  Thread Thread[ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer,5,main] died {org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:640)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:727)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:657)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.writeCheck(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:153)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor$2.run(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:117)
at org.apache.activemq.thread.SchedulerTimerTask.run(SchedulerTimerTask.java:33)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Some of Queries configured in CEP

```
<cep:query name="xxxBuildUpQuery">
<cep:expression><![CDATA[from  xxxCEPIntgDataStream[interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx' or interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx'or 
                               interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx' or interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx' or 
                               interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx' or interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxxx-xxx' or 
                               interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx' or 
                               interfaceInformationInterfaceName=='xxx-xxx' ]#window.time(60000)
insert into buildUpStream interfaceInformationInterfaceName, count(interfaceInformationxxxId) as noOfInflowMsgs group by interfaceInformationInterfaceName]]></cep:expression>
<cep:output brokerName="activemqJmsBroker" topic="xxxBuildUpInfoTopic">
  <cep:xmlMapping>
    <xxxAnalytics>
      <buildUpInfo>
        <interfaceName>{interfaceInformationInterfaceName}</interfaceName>
        <buildUpPerMin>{noOfInflowMsgs}</buildUpPerMin>
      </buildUpInfo>
    </xxxAnalytics>
  </cep:xmlMapping>
</cep:output>
</cep:query>
<cep:query name="xxxQueueDepthQuery">
<cep:expression><![CDATA[from xxxIntgrQueueDepthData_v1
insert into xxxIntgrQueueDepthStream flowName,appName, queueDepth]]>  </cep:expression>
<cep:output brokerName="activemqJmsBroker" topic="xxxIntgrQueueDepthTopic">
  <cep:xmlMapping>
    <xxxAnalytics>
      <queueDepthInfo>
        <flowName>{flowName}</flowName> 
        <appName>{appName}</appName>
        <depth>{queueDepth}</depth>
      </queueDepthInfo>
    </xxxAnalytics>
  </cep:xmlMapping>
</cep:output>
</cep:query>
<cep:query name="xxxClockDataQuery">
  <cep:expression><![CDATA[from testStream
insert into testOutClockDataStream AEDateTime]]></cep:expression>
  <cep:output brokerName="activemqJmsBroker" topic="xxxClockDataTopic">
    <cep:xmlMapping>
      <xxxClockFeed>
        <data>
          <XXDateTime>{XXDateTime}</XXDateTime>
        </data>
      </xxxClockFeed>
    </cep:xmlMapping>
  </cep:output>
 </cep:query>
 <cep:query name="xxxSimltrPaymntAvgQuery_1">
  <cep:expression><![CDATA[from xxxCEPIntgDataStream#window.time(15000)
    insert into xxxSimltrPymntAvgData avg(amount) as avgAmount, currency group by currency]]></cep:expression>
  <cep:output brokerName="activemqJmsBroker" topic="xxxAvgPaymntDetails">
    <cep:xmlMapping>
      <xxxAnalytics>
        <avgPaymentData>
          <avgAmount>{avgAmount}</avgAmount>
          <currency>{currency}</currency>
        </avgPaymentData>
      </xxxAnalytics>
    </cep:xmlMapping>
  </cep:output>
```

Thanks
Rajiv Patil

Comment: What caused the above out of memory issue?

Comment: Rajiv, It is hard to find the reason for OOM issue with just an exception... We need more details 1) At what situation this OOM occurred 2) Is cassendra is running in the background 3) What is the version of the CEP? 4) Is there any pattern of OOM? 5) Please attach the heap dump (you can find that at <CARBON_HOME/repository/logs>...

Comment: Thanks @Mohanadarshan. I have edited the post with the suggested info.. please help

Comment: @Ratha not sure what has caused the OOM.  I have edited my post with additional details.  The size of data flowing into CEP is not that much, but we have data being fed pretty frequently to CEP (the heartbeat from ESB every 15 sec, JMX Agent connecting to the CEP every 15 min, another housekeeping data every 15 min)

Comment: Is it possible to attach the carbon.log and the corresponding siddhi query that running at this OOM situation???

Comment: @Mohanadarshan - I do have the carbon log when the OOM happened but not sure how can i attach it in stackoverflow.  The active CEP queries have been added in the original post.   Thanks

Comment: We are trying to reproduce the issue with the given details.. Will update you if we are able to reproduce it...

Comment: @Mohanadarshan, we were able to reproduce the error. We kept the CEP running and noticed that after 6 days 23 hours when the thread count reached 32000 ~ the CEP gave same OOM. This is very similar to first occurence that time also the thread count was around 32K at time OOM. Do u think its a thread leak ? coz since past 6 days of monitoring we noticed that thread count increases linearly at count of 180-200 per hour

Comment: @Mohanadarshan, we see this error.. which is same as what we saw earlier .. [2013-06-10 05:31:49,040] ERROR -  Thread Thread[ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer,5,main] died {org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Comment: @Mohanadarshan  we zeroed down the issue to a bucket which was using timeBatch window. Subsequently we have verified that whenever we have timeBatch window in the query the thread count starts to ramp up linearly.. and at some point will reach around 32K and will cause CEP to go OOM on a 4 GB linux box with 1.5GB max heap size allocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like timeBatch window is the issue, we had couple of queries using that... once removed the thread ramp up was arrested. Probably the timeBatch window feature of CEP needs more testing.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the Siddhi Manager initiates a scheduled thread pool with Integer.MAX_VALUE as core pool size. That's mean that every request will create a new thread, with no time out policy. (ref: [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html))

Until WSO2 fix this problem, you can change the size of this thread pool. P.e., in the class org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager change the line:

> this.siddhiContext.setScheduledExecutorService(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

(line 77 in [SiddhiManager](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/dependencies/commons/siddhi/1.1.0-wso2v1/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/SiddhiManager.java) ver 1.1.0-wso2v1)

to this one:

> this.siddhiContext.setScheduledExecutorService(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100));

This change will create a core pool size of 100, a maximum pool size of Integer.MAX_VALUE, and the idle threads (over the core pool size) will be removed as soon as they finish.