# WSO2 CEP - memory leak

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have a problem about WSO2 CEP.
Please advice or fix this problem.

Environment is below.
1) CEP version is 2.1.0.
2) TimeBatch Window and patterns query is used.

```
from RootStream#window.timeBatch(10000)
insert into AvgOneStream avg(watt) as avgOne
```

```
from every one = AvgOneStream[avgOne >= 10] ->
     two = AvgTwoStream[avgTwo >= 220] ->
     three = AvgThreeStream[avgThree >= 440]
within 10000
insert into Stream one.avgOne as avgOne, two.avgTwo as avgTwo, three.avgThree as avgThree
```

Problem is below.
1) Out of memory occurs.
2) Number of threads is increased.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in the time windows in CEP version 2.1.0 and a fix was previously  mentioned on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17232907/2134453).

In newer versions of CEP (3.0.0 onwards), this is fixed.